# Robot Framework - How to import SeleniumLibrary keywords implementation/documentation in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, robotframework

I am new to robot framework and I am using eclipse. I also installed RED plugin.
I opened the [demo project](https://github.com/robotframework/WebDemo) in eclipse. And opened resource.robot file.

Here's my question. When I `Ctrl+click` on "Login Page Should Be Open", I get redirected to implementation of the keyword.

Now, I want to do the same with "Open Browser", "Maximize Browser Window" etc

How can I do that?

The main difference between them is that the former is a user defined keyword while the latter is a SeleniumLibrary keyword.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

```
*** Keywords ***
Open Browser To Login Page
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${BROWSER}    NONE    ${REMOTE URL}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Selenium Speed    ${DELAY}
    Login Page Should Be Open

Login Page Should Be Open
    Title Should Be    Login Page
```

Comment: I don't think there is way to do that. Not in eclipse but in other IDE's as well.

Comment: However you may want to try this out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37872633/5400362

Comment: Not for Eclipse - thus not an answer, but a comment - but in PyCharm as long as you've set as "Project Interpreter" the python environment you have those libraries installed and have a language plugin (like IntelliBot) , the go-to-definition works on all external python libraries; it even works for the framework's ones. This is mainly a reply to @Dev's comment, not random advocating to switch IDEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the replies. The solution is to add robot nature (Right click on the project > Robot Framework > Add Robot Nature to the project and add the selenium library in the red.xml as shown below.

Add selenium library to red.xml
[image]

Ctrl+click on the 'Open Browser' keyword then you'll be redirected to implementation of the keyword
[image]

Note: I also installed PyDev plugin and setup Phyton Interpreter in eclipse